# How do I specify days if I want to create an alarm app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, alarm

I want to create an alarm app in wp7. I can set basic alarms but I cannot give them functionality of what days they need to run on. How do I do that?

Comment: Why, oh why, did you put WP7 twice in your title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [RecurrenceInterval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.recurrenceinterval%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property in Alarm. If you want to set alarm to specific days, you can set several alarms on coming days, an when user launched your app - update alarms accordingly.

Comment: So if i set the alarms for the current week and the user doesnt open the app for more than a week, his alarms wont go on the next week...I think thats just stupid on the API side...no other solution?

Comment: @user1097244 you could tell the user about this limitation, and use a background task daily to show how many days are left before their alarms won't work anymore. If you combined a tile with '2 days left, please open app' with a cool image, a user might actually like having it as a live tile.